# Use data value for lodash.throttle timeout in vue.js SFC

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

Hey to all people here,

I am fairly new to Vue.js but I think I start getting in to it. However, I have a problem with my Single File Components in combination with lodashs throttle() function. Here is what my component looks so far:

```html
<template>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-shorttext">
        <label v-bind:for="itemId"
               v-text="label"></label>
        <input v-bind:name="itemId"
               v-bind:id="itemId"
               v-model="input"
               type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</template>

<script>
    import _ from 'lodash'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                itemId: '123450',
                label: 'Test Label',
                input: 'Test value',
                throttled: 200
            };
        },
        watch: {
            input: function (value) {
                this.throttledValuePush(value)
            }
        },
        methods: {
            throttledValuePush: _.throttle(function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            }, this.throttled)
        }
    };
</script>

<style>
    .fieldset-shorttext {
        border:0;
    }
</style>
```

When I run this in my browser I get an error that **this.throttled (used as the timeout parameter for my throttle() function) is not defined**. It works when I use a fixed value such as **200** for example. But I can't get it running by using the value of the "`throttled`" data variable.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT: I added a sandbox example here:** https://codesandbox.io/s/434490z5v9

Comment: what went wrong with my answer i updated it based on this [`article`](https://alligator.io/vuejs/lodash-throttle-debounce/) and it works fine [`here`](https://codesandbox.io/s/3rxoxknm16)

Comment: Yes but I want to use the data variable, NOT a fixed value like 200. But thank you very much anyways =)

Comment: you're welcome and thanks to @MarvinIrwin since he learnt us something very valuable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` object is instantiated and its properties put into `this` **after** `methods`, you **cannot** use `this.throttle` at that time.

Instead, You can use `this.throttl` in the `mounted` lifecycle hook

```
methods: {
    throttledValuePush: undefined,
},
mounted() {
    this.throttledValuePush = _.throttle((value) => console.log(value), this.throttled);
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your explanation, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Great answer thank you, when i try to answer a question i can't to found the solution, it will be my problem also, and someone could find the solution i feel happy and i learn something new